# Error trying to generate some faces and store in another folder

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use transfer learning to train an image recognition model, I want to generate faces in one of my folders into another folder. This is my solution

```
# Loading the HAARCascade Face Detector 
face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Directory of image of persons to perform extraction
mypath = "./where_i_want_to_extract_face_from/"
image_file_names = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
print("Image name successfully collected")

for image_name in image_file_names:
    person_image = cv2.imread(mypath+image_name)
    face_info = face_detector.detectMultiScale(person_image, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in face_info:
        face = person_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        explorer = cv2.resize(face, (128, 128), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    path = "./folder_to_save_the_extracted_faces/" + "face_" + image_name 
    cv2.imwrite(path, explorer )
    cv2.imshow("face", explorer )
    
    cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, running the code above keeps generating:

```
NameError: name 'explorer' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `explorer` is not defined outside of the `for (x,y,w,h) in face_info` loop. You can not use it because it is out of scope.

Comment: what stateMachine said is wrong. it *would* be defined after the loop, if the loop ran *at least once*. `face_info` is empty. the loop didn't run. -- dear OP, please learn how to debug python programs. NameError one of the simplest types of error in python. such questions are considered "low quality".

Comment: Ah yes, you are right @Christoph Rackwitz, I had a bit of a lapse there. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't understand how, but restarting my IDE fixed the error for me.

Comment: that can't have "fixed" it. what fixed it is that your video feed now always contains a face. your code failed because there were no faces in at least one video frame.

Comment: That's why I'm still surprised because I didn't change anything than restarting the IDE. Although from my experience, even if there is no face, face_detector will simply not be able to detect any face, not that I will be getting name_error issue.